# php oop call to a general function eachtime

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to loop through this

```
public static function CSS() {

        $filenames = array(
            "css/tableStyles.css"=>"function1()",
            "css/resetCSS.css"=> "function2()"
        );
        foreach ($filenames as $filename=>$method){
            CSS::$method;
        }


    }

   public function1(){
//do something
   }


   public function2(){
//do something else
   }

}
```

I get a run time error. 
any tips?

edit:
thank arxanas,

The answer is :

```
$filenames = array(
                "css/tableStyles.css"=>"function1",
                "css/resetCSS.css"=> "function2"
            );
            foreach ($filenames as $filename=>$method){
                CSS::$method();
            }
```

Comment: what is the text of the error?

Comment: Why not mark Arxanas as the answer to your question.

Comment: thanks, i thought i allready did.. done. thanks again arxans!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `CSS::function1` even exist? You haven't shown it. And in any case, you shouldn't have parentheses where you have `function1()`. Instead use

```
$filenames = array(
    "css/tableStyles.css"=>"function1",
    "css/resetCSS.css"=> "function2"
);
foreach ($filenames as $filename=>$method){
    CSS::$method();
}
```

Comment: hi again, arxans, I tried more genelraiztion of this function -> I want to pass the class name too and then call it => "css/tableStyles.css"=>"CSS::function1", "css/tableStyles.js"=>"JS::function5", but it doesn't work..

Comment: @devmonster That is a new question, so you should start a new question to have it answered.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define function1 and function2 as static.

```
    public static function1(){
//do something
   }


   public static function2(){
//do something else
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call non static method from static method. You need to define `function1` and `function2` like static methods. And also you call property not method.

```
public static function CSS() {

        $filenames = array(
            "css/tableStyles.css"=>"function1()",
            "css/resetCSS.css"=> "function2()"
        );
        foreach ($filenames as $filename=>$method){
            CSS::$method();
        }


    }

   public static function1(){
//do something
   }


   public static function2(){
//do something else
   }

}
```